show that strong duality holds
I try to show that for the given problem, strong dualty holds:
Primal Problem:
$$ Min  \text{ x,y}: \sqrt{\lVert x \lVert^2+4}+a^T y+\lVert x \lVert $$
$$ \text{s.t }\\  Bx+Cy \leq d  \text{ , }\lVert y \lVert \leq1 $$
$\text{ where a } \in R^n , B,C \in R^{m \times n}  \text{ and } d\in R^m \\$
For the given question I know that $BB^T \succ0$
To show that strong duality holds I have to show that the primal problem is convex which indeed is convex and that Slater's condition holds, so far I choose y=0 but don't know how to satisfy the first inequality.
Thanks!

Nice move to choose $y=0$.
We have $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Since $BB^T \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$,
$BB^T \succ 0$ impliy that $m \le n$ and $B$ has $m$ linearly independent rows. The rank of $B$ is $m$ and hence its columns spans $\mathbb{R}^m$
Let $e$ be the all one vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $x_0$ be a vector that in $\mathbb{R}^m$ that satisfies $Bx_0=d-e$.
Hence we have $Bx_0+C0=d-e < d$.
Hence $(x_0, 0)$ is an interior point and the Slater's condition holds.
